# Summing up booleans in core data vs nsnumbers

Tags: swift, core-data

Currently I am building a statistics application and currently I have my core data model setup to have 1 object nsnumber recorded for wins and 1 object for losses each time a player the player records the stat. These objects are just the number 1. However after re-evaluating my model I realized I could just have have 1 attribute for each of the 9 options that record a boolean of true or false and then sum that up I have posted a copy of my current data model before I make that change.

I want to see if I am correct on that. Also if I did go down that way how would I sum up the total of true objects vs false objects to do a a multiplication to get the statistic how would I go about doing this with boolean objects? What would the code look like? I am still learning programming language and decided to start working with a project like this using core data....!!
[image: final simplified core data model]
[image: second attempt at simplifying the model]
[image: initial model which is hideous by design]

Answer (score 2):

Your model is seriously flawed. You are practically hardcoding data into the model. That is problematic on so many levels.

For example: paladins, priests and rogues should be reflected as data, not attribute names of entities. You should abstract these things away into some entity that has a `name` attribute.

Less importantly, you are using plurals as entity names. That could also be misleading, as entities describe categories of data, not tables. Entity names with verbs in them, like "StoreUsersDeck" are even more outlandish. It's a deck of cards, so why not "Deck"? A similar argument can be made for your attribute and relationship names.

I do not understand your model, but here is an example to illustrate the kind of simplification you should be looking for:

```
Deck
  -name
  -(categories) <<-------------------------->> Category
                                                -name
  -(cards)      <--------------------------->> Card
                                                -(category)
```

Finally, to your point of booleans/numbers: simplifying the data model should help here as well. I am assuming that for each category you can only have one result, a count of wins or a count of losses.

```
Result
  -isWin [boolean]
  -count [number]
  -(category) <<--------------> Category
```

or `Result` with `winCount` and `loseCount` if this is required.

Comment: I have the Class entity containing the classes as a boolean that saves a true/false statement that determines the archetype. As far as everything else I agree I just rushed to make the data model one day and will be cleaning it up a lot over the next 24 hours. So for the results I should have 2 separate one containing the true/false win loss record then another entity with the classes that they faced?

Comment: Result can be to-many from Deck. My idea was that `isWin` captures both wins and losses. If, however, both are possible, you could have instead `winCount` and `loseCount`.

Comment: I want to be able to keep track of the wins and losses in a tableview afterwords that breaks down exactly which match was faced and the end result so I figured I needed both...it didn't occur to me to separate the classes into its own entity I definitely see how that would be much cleaner....I am working on that now.

Comment: I cleaned up my core data model a ton see if this is more clear to read and edited my initial post with the newer picture

Comment: Still flawed. Eliminate VSClass (it is the same as Class) and reduce the attributes of Class to a single `name` (if you need more, use to-many relationships where you have now to-one). Also you should include your initial data model in the question for the benefit of others.

Comment: ill place is back in...the only thing i am not completely understanding is why i would reduce it to a single name? I need to be able to compare the stats for multiple classes to figure out the players best class...it seems difficult to do it under a single name attribute whereas if i leave it as it is i can code in the comparison easier.

Comment: I changed the data model again similar to your suggestions changing the Class to a single name didn't make much sense if i wanted a boolean to keep track for all the different classes in a way that I could call back to without having to write a ton of code to ask for the name each time. It seems much simpler to just create a loop that checks a true false of the class model but let me know what you think of the most recent changes!

Comment: The way I thought about the class option is basically like this the user will only be able to have 1 class per deck lets say to that is a to one relationship, but there can be many decks of the same type of class so it should be to-many correct? The 'name' idea just involves a lot of parsing for specific names then using those names. Whereas if you have a true/false of a data object you can just run a check of true/false in a loop and if one object comes back true that must be the class associated with the deck. I hope I am right on this?

Comment: It seems you are way over your head with this. If you do not understand that a single `name` attribute is superior in design and how it can be used with a to-many relationship in filters and queries, you should not be writing a stats app.

Comment: I didn't say that to-many wasn't superior in most cases...I said for the sake of simplicity and not having to write extra filters and queries for each object maybe having a simple loop would be faster in the prospect of coding. I mean will my method bog down the apps processing my data model slower than yours? If thats the case then obviously I would switch to that method...I just wasn't sure it would make much of a difference in the end as the loop will process things probably a bit quicker having a simple true/false check for the end result. I am learning core data so if this is not the case

Comment: There is no ego about mine being superior or yours just simply learning about this is enough so that I can actually grasp how to use core data better...I am new into this and working on this has been awesome.